# NativeScript Angular : Dynamic content for tabView

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I managed to add taView items dynamically my question now is how to bind a component eg. SubComponent(which will display the right content )
My code sample

```
<TabView (selectedIndexChange)="onIndexChanged($event)" selectedColor="#FF0000" iosIconRenderingMode="alwaysOriginal" sdkExampleTitle sdkToggleNavButton>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let tab of tabList">
        <StackLayout *tabItem="tab">
            ----
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-container>
</TabView>
```

I tried with router-oultet in the ng-for no success
Thanks in advance